# How to pass unique id into all JMS messages weblogic

Tags: java, jms, integration, weblogic-10.x, osb

I am struggling with a problem and yet to resolve it. In Oracle WebLogic OSB I have a bunch of proxy services. Let's say each of them should pass a parameter to a jms queue with unique identifier so I will be able to aggregate several messages together on the server side in Java. What I do not know is how to pass this unique header between proxises so it doesn't get lost. Will you guys help me out here? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GroupId to aggregate messages belonging to a group. This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0602_currie/0602_currie.html) talks about grouping messages in IBM MQ. There must be something similar in WebLogic too.